# Screen refusing to refresh after action

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I am new to java and currently working on a project. I am trying to get familiar with the bluetooth. So far, i have been able to turn on and off bluetooth from within the app. The problem i have is that the screen does not refresh after an action has been carried out. For example, when i turn on the bluetooth, it comes on, but the text in the textview doesn't update until i flip the phone over. Same for when i disconnect. Here is my code

```
package com.example.bluetooth;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Button button;
TextView update;
CharSequence enabled = "Bluetooth Enabled";
CharSequence disabled = "Bluetooth disabled";
CharSequence connect = "Connect";
CharSequence disconnect = "Disconnect";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUp();
    action();
    }

private void action() {
    if (button.getText() == connect) {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btAdapter.enable();

            }
        });
    }

    if (button.getText() == disconnect) {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btAdapter.disable();

            }
        });
    }

}

private void setUp() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    update = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {

        update.setText("Bluetooth is enabled");
        button.setText(disconnect);

    }

    else {

        update.setText("Bluetooth is disabled");
        button.setText(connect);


    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I see wrong:

1. You are calling the method in charge of updating the TextView (`setIp()`) only once, since `onCreate()` is only called once per Activity creation. Since turning the [adapter on/off, is done outside the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable%28%29), you will have to make a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen for `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` then update accordingly.
2. You are comparing CharSequences with `==`. You should instead use Strings and then use `.equals()` since that will ensure a deep comparison. Only thing you need to change besised the type declarations are to add `.toString()` after `getText()`. For example `button.getText().toString()`

Edit: A simple (but messy) solution can be making the receiver dynamically and registering it. Now, keep in mind that you only have to call `setUp()` once, like you did before. Something like the below code might work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


  BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
  Button button;
  TextView update;
  String enabled = "Bluetooth Enabled";
  String disabled = "Bluetooth disabled";
  String connect = "Connect";
  String disconnect = "Disconnect";
  BroadcastReceiver receiver;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    setUp();
    action();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause()
  {
    try{
      unregisterReceiver (receiver);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException ie)
    {
      ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  private void action() {
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener (){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
            btAdapter.disable();
        else
            btAdapter.enable();

    }

  });

 }

  private void setButtonText ()
  {
    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {       
      update.setText("Bluetooth is enabled");
      button.setText(disconnect);
    }

    else {

      update.setText("Bluetooth is disabled");
      button.setText(connect);
    }
  }
  private void setUp() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    update = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    setButtonText();

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        setButtonText();

      }

    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver (receiver, filter);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried calling the 'setup()' again in each of the onclicklisteners, but it still doesn't work. I also changed from '==' to '.equals()'

Comment: @hauwamusa Enabling disabling is an async call, so you will have to make a broadcast receiver. I'll try to make a code sample soon.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I will be on the look out for your sample.

Comment: Thank you so so much @A--C ! I finally got it working perfectly thanks to your sample.